# how to loop JSON object and create a HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

iCreated a form to input bowling score data and i need to loop through this JSON object and put it on a html table. i want to make the table inside the if condition. how to do it?

this is the Controller class function

```
public ActionResult GetAllBowlingScoreData(MemberScore recObj)
        {
            
            string Result = "SUCCESS";
            string Message;

            try
            {
                List<MemberScore> mySessionData = Session["MySession"] as List<MemberScore>;
             

                ValidationResponse response = ValidateMemberScore(recObj);
                if (response.isValid)
                {
                    if(mySessionData==null)
                    {
                        mySessionData = new List<MemberScore>();
                    }
                    mySessionData.Add(recObj);
                    Session["MySession"] = mySessionData;

                    Message = "Validated Memeber";

                    //do something if its valid
                    return Json(CommonUtil.MapJSON(CommonUtil.Serialize(mySessionData), Result, Message));
                }
                else
                {
                    Session["MySession"] = null;
                    Result = "FAIL";
                    Message = response.message;

                    return Json(CommonUtil.MapJSON(null, Result, Message), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogError(ex);
            }
            return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here is the  view

```
 
<div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading marginRow">
    <div class="col-lg-11 marginRow">
        <h2>Bowling Score Management</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row wrapper wrapper-content" style="padding-bottom:0px">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins collapsed">
        <div class="ibox-title ">
            <div class="collapse-link" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;margin:0px">
                <h5>Filter</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-tools" style="display:inline-block;float:right">
                <a class="collapse-link">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
            @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
            <form id="BowlingManagementFilterForm" autocomplete="on">

                <div class="row marginRow">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                        <label>Member</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control marginRow dp" id="MEMBER_NAME" name="MEMBER">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>Games Played</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control marginRow dp MEMBER_NAME" id="GAMES_PLAYED" name="GAMES_PLAYED">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row marginRow">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>Max Score</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control marginRow dp" id="MAX_SCORE" name="MAX_SCORE">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>Total Score</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control marginRow dp" id="TOTAL_SCORE" name="TOTAL_SCORE">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>Average Score</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control allow-numeric" id="AVERAGE_SCORE" name="AVERAGE_SCORE">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <div class="row marginRow">
                <div class="col-md-12 ">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="FilterGrid()">Search</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="ClearFilterandGrid()">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>




    </div>


    




</div>


   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //     alert("Welcome");

        });

        function FilterGrid() {
            //alert($('#BowlingManagementFilterForm').serialize());

            $.ajax({
                url: appPath + '/Core/CommonServices/GetAllBowlingScoreData',
                method: 'post',
                type: 'json',
                data: $("#BowlingManagementFilterForm").serialize(),
                success: function (output, result, message) {
                    
                    if (output.result == "SUCCESS") {
                        
                        var AddedData = JSON.parse(output.data);

                       
                     

                        //loop json list
                        //create html tabel from javascript/jquery 
                        //apped tr from jqeuery 

                        //-----
                        //loop json list
                        //append tr from jqeuery 
                        // ID #


                        // append a html tag  to div tag/





                    }
                    else {
                        alert(output.message);
                    }
                }
            });


        }

        function ClearFilterandGrid() {
            alert("Clear Clicked");
        }

    </script>
```

the data is already loaded to the  AddedData variable. it would be a great help if anyone can help me how to do this. thanks!!

i tried to add this to the script but it did not work.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //     alert("Welcome");

        });

        function FilterGrid() {
            //alert($('#BowlingManagementFilterForm').serialize());

            $.ajax({
                url: appPath + '/Core/CommonServices/GetAllBowlingScoreData',
                method: 'post',
                type: 'json',
                data: $("#BowlingManagementFilterForm").serialize(),
                success: function (output, result, message) {
                    
                    if (output.result == "SUCCESS") {
                        
                        var AddedData = JSON.parse(output.data);

                        var table = $('<table>'); // Create a new table element

                        // Create table header
                        var thead = $('<thead>').appendTo(table);
                        var headerRow = $('<tr>').appendTo(thead);

                        // Customize table headers
                        $('<th>').text('Member').appendTo(headerRow);
                        $('<th>').text('Games Played').appendTo(headerRow);
                        $('<th>').text('Max Score').appendTo(headerRow);
                        $('<th>').text('Total Score').appendTo(headerRow);
                        $('<th>').text('Average Score').appendTo(headerRow);

                        // Create table body
                        var tbody = $('<tbody>').appendTo(table);
                        AddedData.forEach(function (data) {
                            var row = $('<tr>').appendTo(tbody);

                            // Customize table cells
                            $('<td>').text(data.Member).appendTo(row);
                            $('<td>').text(data["Games Played"]).appendTo(row);
                            $('<td>').text(data["Max Score"]).appendTo(row);
                            $('<td>').text(data["Total Score"]).appendTo(row);
                            $('<td>').text(data["Average Score"]).appendTo(row);
                        });


                        // Append the table to a div tag or any other container element
                        $('#ibox-content').empty().append(table);


                     

                        //loop json list
                        //create html tabel from javascript/jquery 
                        //apped tr from jqeuery 

                        


                    





                    }
                    else {
                        alert(output.message);
                    }
                }
            });


        }

        function ClearFilterandGrid() {
            alert("Clear Clicked");
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Which error message did you get? Maybe can't loop over `AddedData`? I think you don't need to use the `JSON.parse` method since you previously set the [data `type`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#data-types) as `json`.

Comment: i did not got any error message. but i'll try to remove the JSON.parse method and try it. Thank you for the help!!